# Custom taxonomy display name issue

Tags: custom-taxonomy

i have created custom taxonomy named Locations , everything is working fine, but whenever i add a taxonomy, everywhere is showing the taxonomy name as Category not as Location, `Like Add New category` and so on ,  in wp-admin

```
function reg_location_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy( 'location', array( 'product' ), array( 'hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Locations', 'singular_label' => 'Location', 'rewrite' => true ) );
    // register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'location', 'product' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'reg_location_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your registration is a bit wrong. You did not provide any of the strings necessary to label you taxonomy correctly. Pass an array to `labels' like this:

```
register_taxonomy( 
  'location', 
  array( 'post' ), 
  array( 
    'hierarchical' => true, 
    'labels' => array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Genres', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Genre', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Genres' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Genres' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Genre' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Genre:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Genre' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Genre' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Genre' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Genre Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Genre' ),
    ), 
    'rewrite' => true 
  ) 
);
```

[I copied that from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Example) so it is for a "Genre" taxonomy, not your "Locations" one but you should see what needs to happen.

Also, pay attention to the keys. There is no `singular_label` that I can see in the Codex. It is `singular_name`.